# Script acts differently in different directories

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, rename

I have a simple script that I pulled out of a larger script dedicated to renaming files with odd characters in the name. I have run this successfully on the same machine within different directories, and as we speak, it is running successfully within a directory but for some reason when running it against a higher level directory it renames the files incorrectly. 
For example I have run this against a folder called UnsortedMusic. 
What it is supposed to do is:

```
/UnsortedMusic/Dir 001/SubDir 001/Song To Sing.flac > /UnsortedMusic/Dir 001/SubDir 001/SongToSing.flac
```

it takes the spaces out of the name, I then have essentially the same code but dedicated towards directories to remove spaces in directory names:

```
/UnsortedMusic/Dir 001/SubDir 001/SongToSing.flac > /UnsortedMusic/Dir001/SubDir001/SongToSing.flac
```

This has worked successfully on other directories but for some reason on one particular dir it is doing someting like this:

```
 /UnsortedMusic/Dir 001/SubDir 001/Song To Sing.flac > /UnsortedMusic/Dir001/SubDir001/UnsortedMusicDir001SubDir001SongToSingflacSongToSingflac
```

As you can see its not only renaming the file with all the directory names its also removing the "." in the .flac which means ill have to change this manually for thousands of files.

This snippet of code is listed below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -e

FolderName="Unsorted" #Dir location to be sorted

# Log Location on Server.
LOG_LOCATION=$(pwd) #/home/user/scripts/logs
exec > >(tee -i $LOG_LOCATION/RenameFile.log)
exec 2>&1
Start by seeing if the new directory allready exists, if not, make it

echo "Looking in $FolderName for files with abnormal characters"
#Rename any directories that might have a weird name structure that could conflict
find ${FolderName} -type f \( -name "* *" -o -name "*(*" -o -name "*[*" -o -name "*&*" \) -print0 | sort -rz | while read -d $'\0' file;
    do
        mv -v "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/$(basename "${file//[^a-zA-z0-9_-.]/}")";
done

#echo "Log Location should be: [ $LOG_LOCATION ]"
echo "Finished Process"
```

Which is part of a larger process script shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -e

NewDirName="TestDirV2" #New Dir name
FolderName="TestDir" #Dir location to be sorted

# Log Location on Server.
LOG_LOCATION=$(pwd) #/home/user/scripts/logs
exec > >(tee -i $LOG_LOCATION/Organizer.log)
exec 2>&1
#Start by seeing if the new directory allready exists, if not, make it
if [ ! -d ${NewDirName} ];
then 
    mkdir -p ${NewDirName}
    chmod -R a+rwx ${NewDirName}
fi

echo "Looking in $FolderName for files with abnormal characters"
#Rename any files that might have a weird name structure that could conflict 
find ${FolderName} -type f \( -name "* *" -o -name "*(*" -o -name "*[*" -o -name "*&*" \) -print0 | sort -rz | while read -d $'\0' file;
    do
        mv -v "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/$(basename "${file//[^a-zA-z0-9_-.]/}")";
done

echo "Looking in $FolderName for directories with abnormal characters"
#Rename any directories that might have a weird name structure that could conflict 
find ${FolderName} -type d \( -name "* *" -o -name "*(*" -o -name "*[*" -o -name "*&*" \) -print0 | sort -rz | while read -d $'\0' file;
    do
        mv -v "$file" "$(dirname "$file")/$(basename "${file//[^a-zA-z0-9_-.]/}")";
done


for FileType in $(find $FolderName -type f | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u)
do


    echo "Finished removing odd characters that may result in problems"

    NewDir=$(echo "${NewDirName}/${FileType}");      

    if [ ! -d ${NewDirName}/${FileType} ];
        then
            echo "$NewDir does not exist"      
            echo "Making $NewDir"
            mkdir -p ${NewDir}
            chmod -R a+rwx ${NewDir}
    fi

    echo "Now looking for renamed $FileType files"
    for FileToMove in $(find ${FolderName} -name "*.${FileType}");
    do  
        echo "Dir to move ${FileToMove}"        
        echo "File to move ${FileToMove##*/}"

        SpecificFile=$(echo "${FileToMove##*/}");       

        echo "Checking to see if $SpecificFile already exist in $NewDir"

        if [ -f ${NewDir}/${SpecificFile} ];
        then    
            x=0
            while [ -f ${NewDir}/${SpecificFile} ]        
                do
                echo "File ${SpecificFile} already exists, renaming"
                SpecificFile=${x}${SpecificFile}
                x=$(( x++ ));
                echo "Renamed to $SpecificFile"
            done
        fi    

    #rsync -rav --progress ${FileToMove} ${NewDir}/${SpecificFile}
    mv -v ${FileToMove} ${NewDir}/${SpecificFile}
    done

done
chmod -R a+rwx ${NewDir}

echo "Log Location should be: [ $LOG_LOCATION ]"
echo "Finished Process"
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't be performing the shell pattern substitution `${file//[^a-zA-z0-9_-.]/}` *before* executing the `basename` command - you are relying on the vagaries of your locale to determine whether `/` is included or excluded from the range `_-.`

Comment: @jsotola - Here is one of the files: `renamed 'Unsorted/Documents2/jet engins/gr180/Combustion chamber 2.jpg' -> 'Unsorted/Documents2/jet engins/gr180/UnsortedDocuments2jetenginsgr180Combustionchamber2jpg'`

Comment: @steeledriver - Ok, I will look into how to change, I just started trying to do some shell scripting a week ago.

Comment: @Star-Bandit Note the comment from steeldriver. `_-.` inside `[...]` is a _range_. You probably want to arrange it so that `-` is the last character in there, or use a proper character class like `[:punct:]` if you actually want a set of characters.